# How to generate executable from LLVM IR

Tags: macos, assembly, llvm

I was reading http://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/#llvm-introduction there is a piece of LLVM IR like this:

```
declare i32 @putchar(i32)

define i32 @add(i32 %a, i32 %b) {
  %1 = add i32 %a, %b
  ret i32 %1
}

define void @main() {
  %1 = call i32 @add(i32 0, i32 97)
  call i32 @putchar(i32 %1)
  ret void
}
```

I wanted to try running this by using `llvm` and `nasm` but failed:

```
llc -march=x86-64 h1.bc -o h1.s
nasm -f macho -o h1.o h1.s
# failed here
```

first lines of the errors are:

```
h1.s:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
h1.s:1: error: parser: instruction expected
h1.s:2: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
h1.s:2: error: parser: instruction expected
h1.s:3: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
h1.s:3: error: parser: instruction expected
h1.s:4: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
```

the code generated from `llc` does not seem to be native OS X Assembly code described at http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/assembly-hello-world-for-os-x

What's the right commands to generate an executable?

Comment: What is the version of nasm? Can you post source of h1.s? Try `nasm -f macho64` for 64-bit code.

Comment: Sounds like `llc` generated assembly for an assembler that uses initial periods for its directives (e.g. the GNU assembler). NASM treats names beginning with a period as local labels.

Comment: @osgx Seems `macho64` is not supported. I pasted more details here: https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/4821d04001d3f1e2445e

Comment: @Michael Is that another set of assembly? (I didn't work on assembly before.)

Comment: There are many different x86 assemblers, and their syntaxes differ even though the instruction set architecture they target is the same.

Answer (score 2):

nasm does not support AT&T assembly syntax hence the error. On OS X you need to use "as" to assemble (and forget about nasm in 99% cases except when explicitly requested)

Comment: Here's the log of running in as: https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/4821d04001d3f1e2445e#file-as_log